# With MDX hos to select first row?

Tags: mdx

I am using sharepoint report builder.

In my data (se picture below) - I would like to get all the first row - the ones with yellow.

[image]

How do i do that.

Here is the MDX code. What should I write to get the yellow rows?

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Antal unikke brugere - Visiteret Tid]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Borger].[Anonym Borgernøgle DPR].[Anonym Borgernøgle DPR].ALLMEMBERS*
        [SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].[Ydelse].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Kalender].[År].[År].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Kalender].[Måned].[Måned].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].&[12.1 Hjemmetrænerforløb]
     ,[SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].&[12.2 Komb. Hjemmetræner & Terapeutforløb]
     ,[SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].&[12.3 Komplekse Rehabiliteringsforløb]
     ,[SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].&[12.7. hverdagsrehab. revis.gr. m. tp.]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {[SundhedOgOmsorg - Modul].[Modul].&[Hjemmehjælp]} ON COLUMNS
    FROM [FrbLis]
  )
)
WHERE 
  [SundhedOgOmsorg - Modul].[Modul].&[Hjemmehjælp]
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

Comment: I enjoyed your question - did you like my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using one of the following iterative `mdx` functions:

[Generate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145526.aspx)  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145526.aspx

[Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx

To use filter is a little more convoluted as you need to specify specific tuples based on their relative positions. Generate is a little more straightforward. I will try to provide an example against the MS `AdvWrks` cube.

I think this is relatively similar to your situation:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Product].[Product Categories].[Product]
    * 
      {
          [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050801]
        : 
          [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050807]
      } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

You would like the rows I've marked in red (there are lots of products with only 1 row)

[image]

So if we now apply the following multi-dimensional expression to the cube:

```
WITH 
  SET [prodSet] AS 
    [Product].[Product Categories].[Product] 
  SET [prodDtSet] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [prodSet] AS P
     ,Head
      (
          P.Current
        * 
          NonEmpty
          (
            {
                [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050801]
              : 
                [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050807]
            }
           ,(
              P.Current
             ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
            )
          )
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,[prodDtSet] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

We get the results required:

[image]

Are you able to adapt my example to your context?

---

I will have a further play and supply a solution using `Filter` (it'll be, in a way, a little more complicated than the Generate approach)

Here is an approach using `Filter`:

```
WITH 
  SET [prodSet] AS 
    [Product].[Product Categories].[Product] 
  SET [prodDtSet] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
        [prodSet]
      * 
        {
            [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050801]
          : 
            [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050807]
        }
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
  SET [prodDtSetFiltered] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [prodDtSet]
     ,
        (NOT 
            [prodDtSet].Item(
            [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal - 1).Item(0)
          IS 
            [prodDtSet].Item(
            [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal - 2).Item(0))
      OR 
        [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal = 1
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,[prodDtSetFiltered] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Results are as following:

[image]

Comment: YES :) It worked - the last one with filter. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RuneFrederiksberg - pleasure - this one was fun.